# IIS - Application under default website redirects to root if I don't have a trailing slash

Tags: iis

I am using the 'Default Web Site' in IIS to add multiple applications underneath it, and I'm finding if I omit a trailing / (when I don't specify a page name) it redirects me to the root application. So for example, the 2 below links work:

- http://server/App1/Default.aspx
- http://server/App1/

But if I enter the below...

- http://server/App1

I get redirected to http://server/Default.aspx instead.

I've ensured the Default Document on my application is correct, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have IIS rewrite module installed and configured at root level i.e. at "Default Website" level?

Comment: Did set any rewrite rule in IIS or any setting in Asp.net application route? If you want to set default document at app1 level, you need to choose app1 and click default document module.